# Python Pivoting dataframe that has mulitple ID columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

from a database I get the following table into a python dataframe `df`:

| FunctionID | FunctionText | FunctionModule | UserGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fct1 | ModX | GroupA |
| 2 | Fct2 | ModX | GroupA |
| 2 | Fct2 | ModX | GroupB |
| 3 | Fct3 | ModY | GroupB |
| 3 | Fct3 | ModY | GroupC |
| . | ... | ... | ... |
| 3000 | Fct3000 | ModZ | GroupF |

My goal is to get a pivot-like table that looks like this one:

| FunctionID | FunctionText | FunctionModule | GroupA | GroupB | GroupC | ... | GroupF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fct1 | ModX | X |  |  | ... |  |
| 2 | Fct2 | ModX | X | X |  | ... |  |
| 3 | Fct3 | ModY |  | X | X | ... |  |
| . | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 3000 | Fct3000 | ModZ |  |  |  | ... | X |

So, the first 3 columns shall stay as is whereas the entries of UserGroup column shall be the added columns of the pivot table.

I tried some approaches like

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=df.iloc[:3],columns='UserGroup',values='UserGroup')
```

but without success. Maybe I have to use `pivot()` or `stack()` or `unstack()` ? But none of those led me to the desired target table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could add an extra column and [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with `aggfunc='first'`:

```
(df
 .assign(value='x') # or value=df['UserGroup'] if you want the names as value
 .pivot_table(index=list(df.columns[:3]),
              columns='UserGroup',
              values='value',
              aggfunc='first',
              fill_value='',
              )
)
```

output:

```
UserGroup                              GroupA GroupB GroupC
FunctionID FunctionText FunctionModule                     
1          Fct1         ModX                x              
2          Fct2         ModX                x      x       
3          Fct3         ModY                       x      x
```

*NB. note that `index=df.iloc[:3]` will also select 'UserGroup', I used `index=list(df.columns[:3])` here*